# which pattern is better to filesystem with millions files?

Tags: linux, architecture, filesystems, text-files, cpu-architecture

I work in a company and we have a problem.
there are a server that received 1000 text files per day, the files have 10MB and the purge roles is 10 days. some files can have 20MB.
we have a problem to list and consult that files, is very onerous to linux that consults.

my questions is: which pattern is better to filesystem with millions files ? what better strategy to store and list many and large files:

thanks  and sorry for bad english! hehe

Comment: I would not store them all in the same folder. This would make `ls` taking very long. What about creating a sub folder for every day? The amount of files itself `10.000` if I got you correctly, shouldn't be a problem for any modern file system.

Comment: the folder that receive is a subfolder! we created subfolders by companies, and some of them submit large and many files...in your idea, we have to create a subfolder in subfolders, correctly? but the secure sector dont want permit the dynamic subfolders creation

Comment: Then the "secure sector" allows to DOS the machine by uploading many files. Good job!

Comment: I believe you might get better and more responses for a question like this in either [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is dedicated to [programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and your does not seem to be directly relevant to programming.